Socket not connecting with App Engine deployed link
I have a socket implemented in my project which is connecting and working on local but when I try to connect using the deployed link (project deployed on GCP GAE) I get Error: Unexpected server response: 400
Things I have tried:

Tried using a flex environment: This leads to GCP throwing this error
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error(s) encountered validating runtime. Your runtime version for nodejs is past End of Support. Please upgrade to the latest runtime version available..
Here is my app.yaml file I'm using:

runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service:

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

network:
  session_affinity: true

For some reason the same file works with nodejs20 when the env is standard, I have also tried adding
runtime_config:
  nodejs_version: "20"


Added adding transports: ["websocket"] as per some documentation I found online
Also initially I was making call with https but later found for socket it needs to be wss but this doesn't seem to work as well

Error as on Postman:
Could not connect to wss://{{deployed_link}}/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Error: Unexpected server response: 400
Request URL: {{hosted_link}}/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket //removed here for privacy
Request Method: GET
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: u2EQKRM0VxyLo6g1/sg==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: {{hosted_link}} //removed here for privacy

Here is socket.io file for more context:
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const {
  userInteraction,
  userInteractionSecondary,
} = require("../controllers/simulationSession.controller");

function createSocketServer(httpServer) {
  const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
      origin: ["http://localhost:3001", "{{deployed_link}}"], //removed link for privacy
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      credentials: true, // Allow cookies and authentication headers
    },
    transports: ["websocket"],
  });
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("user-interaction", userInteraction);
    socket.on("user-interaction-helper", userInteractionSecondary);
  });
}

module.exports = { createSocketServer };

Can someone please provide a resolution, been struggling for hours lol


You can't use sockets on Google App Engine Standard (see documentation; search for "socket")

For Google App Engine Flex, the documentation says



Starting in Node.js version 18, you must specify the version of the operating system.

So you need to do something like
runtime_config:
    operating_system: "ubuntu22"
    runtime_version: "20"

